# Как отслеживать, а затем скрывать или показывать при определенных условиях элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется страница, на которой находится n-ое кол-во tabs(вкладок), на каждой вкладке есть автоматически создаваемый элемент в виде кнопки *"Удалить"* и ссылки на загруженный ранее файл, рядом кнопка `input[type="file"]`, они в одном блоке. Вложенность везде большая, `id` у всех элементов формируются автоматом и все разные.  Как отследить каждый блок, скрыть инпуты если есть кнопка удалить и показать, если кнопка отсутствует?  Примерный код блока с кнопками:

```js
$('.fabrikSubElementContainer').each(function(i,elem){
    if($(this).is('span[class="fabrikUploadDelete"]')){
      $(this).find('label').hide();
      $(this).find('span[class="fileInputText"]').hide();
    }else{
      $(this).find('label').show();
      $(this).find('span[class="fileInputText"]').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="fabrikSubElementContainer">
 <span class="fabrikUploadDelete" id="doc_scan_0_delete_span">
  <button class="btn button" data-file="/docs/.../NNkPdG0NFR.pdf" data-join-pk-val="4">Удалить</button> 
  <a class="download-archive fabrik-filetype-pdf" title="NNkPdG0NFR.pdf" href="http://.../NNkPdG0NFR.pdf">NNkPdG0NFR.pdf</a>
 </span>
 <br>
 <label for="doc_scan_0" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0px 7px; border-radius: 0px;">Выберите документ</label>
 <input class="fabrikinput" style="opacity: 0; z-index: -1; display: none; " name="doc_scan[0]" type="file" accept=".pdf" id="doc_scan_0">
 <span style="padding-left: 10px" class="fileInputText">Документ не выбран</span>
</div>
```

Comment: а как Вы думали сделать? или может быть есть какие - то наработки? т.к. ваша задача довольно тривиальна

Comment: @ddeadlink, на данный момент пробую реализовать с помощью `.each( callback( [index, Element] ) )` с вложенным условием

Comment: ,обновите вопрос с примером кода (более детального, нежели просто именем нативной ф-и которую вы хотели бы применить)

Comment: @ddeadlink, обновил

Comment: не уверен что это ответ, поэтому напишу в коментарий . единственное где Вы ошиблись - это в условии. Вы сами написали, что нужно отследить каждый блок, скрыть инпуты если есть кнопка удалить и показать, если кнопка отсутствует. Так зачем вы проверяете в цикле span? проверяйте для примера `$(this).find('button[class="button"]')` - для проверки кнопки в узле

Comment: @ddeadlink, уже разобрался, но спасибо, что откликнулся. К тому же твой ответ оказался правильным, но дошел я до него сам. Спасибо тебе еще раз!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже сам разобрался.

```js
$('.fabrikSubElementContainer').each(function(i,elem){
  if($(this).find('span[class="fabrikUploadDelete"]').length ){
    $(this).find('label').hide();
    $(this).find('span[class="fileInputText"]').hide();
  }else{
    $(this).find('label').show();
    $(this).find('span[class="fileInputText"]').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: метод `length` тут можно считать лишним. т.к Вы проверяете на наличие элемента в узле. у вас условие и так возвращает `true || false `, без данного метода

Comment: @ddeadlink, проверил, без `length` почему-то работает только `hide()`, а вот `show()` уже не срабатывает почему-то.

Comment: потому, что Вы проверяете на наличие в узле `$(this).find('span[class="fabrikUploadDelete"]')`, и если вы хотите применить к нему метод `show` то очевидно, что данного элемента в узле нету - того и не работает, поэтому я предлагал где-то выше искать не span а кнопку